# Store and retrieve set of functions according to options

Tags: javascript

I have a set of functions to run according to combined options. Options are `easier/harder`, `add/multiply`, `wait/nowait`, `1/-1`.

You can see the whole module [here](https://github.com/hadrienj/StaircaseJS/blob/master/Staircase.js).

For now I have put all functions in an object to be able to access them according to the options. For instance:

```
var stair = {
  down: 3,
  sameStairCount: 0,
  sameStairMax: 3,
  successiveBad: 0,
  successiveGood: 0,
  up: 2,
  val: [100],
}

tasks['easier']['add']['wait']['1'](stair);
```

**Question: What other ways I could use to store and retrieve those functions?**

Bellow is the object containing the methods.

```
var tasks = {
  easier: {
    add: {
      noWait: {
        '1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood = 0;
          stair.successiveBad++;
          return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] - stair.factor *
            (stair.factor / stair.up);
        },
        '-1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood = 0;
          stair.successiveBad++;
          return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] + stair.factor *
            (stair.factor / stair.up);
        }
      },
      wait: {
        '1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood = 0;
          stair.successiveBad++;
          if (stair.successiveBad >= stair.up) {
            // change value only if sufficient successive good values
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] - stair.factor;
          } else {
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1];
          }
        },
        '-1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood = 0;
          stair.successiveBad++;
          if (stair.successiveBad >= stair.up) {
            // change value only if sufficient successive good values
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] + stair.factor;
          } else {
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1];
          }
        }
      }
    },
    multiply: {
      noWait: {
        '1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood = 0;
          stair.successiveBad++;
          return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] / Math.pow(stair.factor,
            stair.down / stair.up);
        },
        '-1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood = 0;
          stair.successiveBad++;
          return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] * stair.factor;
        }
      },
      wait: {
        '1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood = 0;
          stair.successiveBad++;
          if (stair.successiveBad >= stair.up) {
            // change value only if sufficient successive good values
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] / stair.factor;
          } else {
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1];
          }
        },
        '-1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood = 0;
          stair.successiveBad++;
          if (stair.successiveBad >= stair.up) {
            // change value only if sufficient successive good values
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] * stair.factor;
          } else {
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  harder: {
    add: {
      wait: {
        '1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood++;
          stair.successiveBad = 0;
          if (stair.successiveGood >= stair.down) {
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] + stair.factor;
          } else {
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1];
          }
        },
        '-1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood++;
          stair.successiveBad = 0;
          if (stair.successiveGood >= stair.down) {
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] - stair.factor;
          } else {
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1];
          }
        }
      },
      noWait: {
        '1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood++;
          stair.successiveBad = 0;
          return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] + stair.factor *
            (stair.factor / stair.down);
        },
        '-1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood++;
          stair.successiveBad = 0;
          return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] - stair.factor *
            (stair.factor / stair.down);
        }
      }
    },
    multiply: {
      wait: {
        '1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood++;
          stair.successiveBad = 0;
          if (stair.successiveGood >= stair.down) {
            // change value only if sufficient successive good values
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] * stair.factor;
          } else {
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1];
          }
        },
        '-1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood++;
          stair.successiveBad = 0;
          if (stair.successiveGood >= stair.down) {
            // change value only if sufficient successive good values
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] / stair.factor;
          } else {
            return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1];
          }
        }
      },
      noWait: {
        '1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood++;
          stair.successiveBad = 0;
          return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] * stair.factor;
        },
        '-1': function (stair) {
          stair.sameStairCount++;
          stair.successiveGood++;
          stair.successiveBad = 0;
          return stair.val[stair.val.length - 1] / Math.pow(stair.factor,
            stair.up / stair.down);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

In each function a part is the same for all `easier` methods. Same thing for `harder` methods.